# What are the differences between the US and UK cuts of the church scene in Kingsman: The Secret Service?

Tags: alternate-version, content-rating, kingsman-the-secret-service

I will try to avoid spoilers but this question is meant for people who HAVE seen the movie.

Apparently there are three different cuts of this movie as far as I know:

- US cut
- UK cut
- Indonesian cut

As I understand it, these cuts vary when it comes to the controversial church scene. The Indonesian cut basically skips the whole thing by cutting from when Colin Firth points the gun at the woman to when he walks out of the church.

My question is what are the differences between the US and UK cuts of this scene? Apparently there are differences because the BBFC (British Board of Film Classification) only granted the film a 15 rating after certain violence was taken out of the film.

Is there a lot taken out or is it maybe some split second shot that was a bit graphic or something?

Comment: From what I can find, the church scene remains intact in the UK version, but other content was either cut or reduced to garner it a rating that would allow kids under 18 to see it, or however the ratings system in the UK works.

Comment: @MattD Thanks Mat! I could very well be mistaken, I thought if anything was going to be cut it would of been that scene hahaha. Love the clip though.

Comment: Did you have people's heads exploding in colory puffs of smoke and fireworks? The US version did, and I'm betting the UK version did and the reason was they wanted a more friendly rating in the UK. Wouldn't really matter in the US because the number of times the word "fuck" is used already pushed it into R territory.

Comment: Yeah, that was definitely in there, that was really funny! There's probably just less blood splatter in the UK edit, its the reason Expendables 3 was only rated PG13 over here.

Comment: The version I saw in Canada had a dose of church violence that made my head spin. Homicidal orgy is how I would describe it, and it was disturbing from the standpoint of how the acts were so quickly occurring, and the length of time it went on. Having brought my kids in, I was horrified.

Comment: @KellyBaker - To be fair on the movie this seems to be a criticism of the Canadian movie ratings system which gives it a 13A or 14A depending on the province - a somewhat lenient rating when compared to elsewhere.  It is an R in the US, and a 15 in the UK (which is a mandatory 15, not something that can be waived by an accompanying adult).  I was fairly shocked to see a child of (approximately) 8 or 9 in our showing, but I don't think we should be watering down a movie just because the rating system is weak or ignored.

Comment: Matthew Vaughn seemed to deny that any cuts were made: http://www.denofgeek.com/movies/matthew-vaughn/33800/matthew-vaughn-interview-kingsman-x-men-stardust-2-007 but the BBFC site says “certain changes were made prior to submission” http://www.bbfc.co.uk/releases/kingsman-secret-service-film Another site suggests a difference of 51 seconds between UK and German versions (but I haven’t verified that): http://www.movie-censorship.com/news.php?ID=8489

Comment: @alexwlchan Thanks Alex, looks like there's controversy not only to the scene itself but how or whether it might have been cut.

Comment: The church scene was also censored in latin america, they showed up to when he shoots the woman, cut, and then colin firth looking around the church when everyone is dead

Comment: I've heard that the church scene was a shot at the westboro church (meaning it was supposed to be the followers who died) which may be a reason it was cut form various versions. This is, of course, unverified.

Comment: @alexwlchan . I wonder what they mean by "certain changes" Does a re-dub count? Maybe they dubbed out some language rather than actually cut footage from the film

Answer (score 2):

I also can confirm that the church scene was censored in Latin America.

I saw the movie in Utah and then last night in Panama.

The church scene in Panama only included the first woman Galahad shoots, cuts of Eggsy's reactions, Merlin's reactions, a couple of guys thrown around from Galahad's POV, Valentine and Gazelle's reactions, then cut to Galahad walking out of the Church I believe. (I am missing some details, but that was pretty much it).

Having seen the church seen again online I estimate about 2:45 to 3:00 minutes being stripped from the film.

Edit: just to clarify, there is A LOT taken out and I was not amused by the censorship.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question in regards to the US vs. UK versions.

Answer (score -1):

One version has a very amusing line of sexual dialogue removed from it, which is a shame. While it doesn't make much difference to the plot the cut is a little disjointed and it is quite obvious that something was cut out which takes you out of the experience. Having seen a version with the original line still in I was expecting to share a laugh with people that hadn't seen the film and was denied that pleasure... which was also a shame as what was quite a surprising and very funny moment just becomes mildly amusing. Still a fantastic film. I won't say the line but the princess says it towards the end of the film if that gives a hint.

Comment: Which version has the dialogue?

Comment: And WHAT is the dialog? Who says it? And why is this answer being upvoted? The OP asks about the church scene and not the movie in general.

Comment: For those still wondering - [spoiler] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2--K85dTZxU