# What happened during the deleted scenes in Kingsman: The Secret Service?

Tags: kingsman-the-secret-service

I watched the movie Kingsman: The Secret Service this weekend, I enjoyed and it is a wonderful movie, but I heard that there were some scenes that has been deleted.

Can you tell what are those scenes?

Comment: I think you're talking about the church scene. Check this question http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/31407/kingsman-the-secret-service-church-scene

Comment: Thank you, for mentioning the link that explain the deleted scenes in kingsman, but all the events mentioned in the discution existed in the movie, people are talking about UK version US version etc..., but is there a version where all the scenes has been not modified (no deleted scenes)

Comment: Can I recommend the comic book, it's no better or worse than the film but it does have a different take on some key aspects of the story that I think you may like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The UK version has a total of 51 seconds censored; I watched the US version (because I live in Paraguay, therefore we consume the American version), which, according to what I saw and read in several websites, is the uncensored version; the German release, I understand is uncensored too. Peter Debruge of the Variety Magazine [explain](http://variety.com/2014/film/reviews/film-review-kingsman-the-secret-service-1201388064/) the parts censored in the UK version:

> *The studio reportedly pushed back on several touchy scenes, including one that plays like a surreal dream sequence from another movie (like Kevin Smith’s “Red State,” perhaps), as hatemongering members of a Westboro-style congregation flip out and spontaneously start attacking one another.*

The reason of the censorship is very simple: ***avoid at all cost the "+18 rating"***.